# Node.js Upload multiple images from user and display it

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am working on an application using express, where users can upload their images and that are stored in mongodb.

I have tried many modules to be able to upload an image in mongoDB. I have really no idea how I can do this in a easy way.

Does any of you know a good and easy way for uploading images and display them?

Comment: Do a little research on "GridFS" and how you can use it to store and retreive files using MongoDB. http://blog.mongodb.org/post/183689081/storing-large-objects-and-files-in-mongodb

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow :). Before asking how to store images in MongoDB, I would consider why you want to do so. There are some good reasons to store images in a database, but typically it is better to store & serve images from a filesystem and only store the path in a database. You can store images directly in MongoDB (either directly as serialised binary within a field in a document, or using the GridFS API for large images). If you're having trouble with a specific image module, that would be a better question to ask for help with (including some code showing what you've tried).